# System Error Error encountered while constructing Graph/TraversalSource - com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph

**Using datastack Cassandra gremlin query. When I tried to run my query(for example g.V().hasLabel('user')) it's throwing this error.**

```
System Error
Error encountered while constructing Graph/TraversalSource - com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, com.datastax.bdp.gcore.datastore.DataStoreException: Failed to execute statement
  at com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.tinkerpop.variables.DsegVariables.<init>(DsegVariables.java:64)
  while locating com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.tinkerpop.variables.DsegVariables
  at com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.GraphModule.configure(Unknown Source) (via modules: com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.DseGraphFactoryImpl$$Lambda$770/304499747 -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.GraphModule)
  while locating org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Graph$Variables
    for parameter 4 at com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.DseGraphImpl.<init>(DseGraphImpl.java:156)
  at com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.GraphModule.configure(Unknown Source) (via modules: com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.DseGraphFactoryImpl$$Lambda$770/304499747 -> com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.GraphModule)
  while locating com.datastax.bdp.graph.impl.DseGraphImpl

1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any additional information for this item?

- version of DSE
- how traversal was executed (through a driver, gremlin console, studio)
- traversal statement

Comment: DataStax Enterprise Edition version is 5.1.2
Gremlin console

Comment: is there anything interesting in `system.log` or `gremlin.log`? Usually at least one of those should contain more detailed information as to what's going on. Could you maybe share those somehow?